# I want to prove the $\frac{d}{dx}\Psi(x,y,y^{\prime})=a_2(x,y,y^\prime)y^{\prime\prime}+a_1(x,y,y^\prime)y^\prime +a_0(x,y,y^\prime)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

I want to prove that $$\frac{d}{dx}\Psi(x,y,y^{\prime})=a_0(x,y,y^{\prime})+a_1(x,y,y^{\prime})y^\prime+a_2(x,y,y^{\prime})y^{\prime\prime}$$.My the paper says since $$a_1(x,y,y^{\prime}), a_2(x,y,y^{\prime}), 
 a_0(x,y,y^{\prime})$$ and their first partial derivatives are continuous then $$\frac{d}{dx}\Psi(x,y,y^{\prime})=a_2(x,y,y^{\prime})y^{\prime\prime}+a_1(x,y,y^{\prime})y^\prime+a_0(x,y,y^{\prime})$$ but i don't understand why that is so.
$$\textbf{Proof}$$
so I have $$\frac{d}{dx}\Psi(x,y,y^{\prime})=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{}^{y^{\prime}}a_2(x_0,y_0,\gamma)d\gamma+\frac{d}{dx}\int_{}^{y}a_1(x_0,\beta,y^{\prime})d\beta+\frac{d}{dx}\int_{}^{x}a_0(\alpha,y,y^{\prime})d\alpha$$ so now by Leibniz rule of integration we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\Psi(x,y,y^{\prime})=a_0(x,y,y^{\prime})+a_1(x_0,y,y^{\prime})y^{\prime}+a_2(x_0,y_0,y)y^{\prime\prime}$$ i need the $x_0$ and $y_0$ as x and y and when I tried google bard it says when
$$a_1, a_2 , a_0$$ and their first partial derivatives are continuous I can replace $x_0, y_0$ by x and y. Does anyone know why that is the case?.